# そこには私一人しかいなかった - why not "私は"?

Tags: grammar, particles

I understand this sentence, but I cannot explain to myself why I don't need any particle for "私一人". What part of speech is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's minimize the example.

- そこには私一人しかいなかった。
- そこには私しかいなかった。
- 私しかいなかった。
- 私しかいない。

Here しか is actually a particle, i.e.
a binding particle (係助詞 kakari-joshi)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_particles